# How can I output a filename without extension in batch?

Tags: batch-file

I'm a real "newbe" in batch and wrote the following script:

```
chdir C:\Users\oRookie\Desktop\batch
dir /b *txt > out.txt
```

The file `out.txt` is created and contains `out.txt` .

So far so good let's try to get more advancaded. Now I want it's content to be just `out`´. So I need some way to delete the fileextension in the Output, but without deleting the fileextension itself. How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just you write `dir /b *txt > out`

Comment: What file would be scanned then to read out from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try for this code and let me know if this what are looking for or not ?

```
@echo off
Set Location=%userprofile%\Desktop\
Set Log=out.txt
if exist %Log% del %Log%
for /f %%i in ('dir /b /a-d %Location%*.txt') do @echo %%~ni >> %Log%
start "" %Log%
```

Comment: Wouldn't work since there won't be a file to read from found, right?

Comment: @oRookie please edit your first question and give more information with example to understand your aim !

Comment: I want to save the true file name (without extension) in the textfile itself. And I still want the textfile to be a textfile.

Comment: After some testing, I actually figured out your solution is the smartest. Thank you a lot. :) - Just one question: What's the difference between putting a `'` arround the `dir /b /a-d %Location%*.txt` and leaving it out?

Answer (score 1):

No idea why you would want to do this but you can do something like this from **command line:**

```
type nul > out.txt | for /r %i in (*.txt) do @echo %~ni >> out.txt
```

Or in a **script:**

```
type nul > out.txt | for /r %%i in (*.txt) do @echo %%~ni >> out.txt
```

Comment: I tried out your script without understanding it tbh. Anyways it's not creating a file. What am I doing wrong? - It is for an Installation script where I grab the version from an existing text file and will later transfer it to my version.txt . I just thought this example is easier to understand.

Comment: Ohh ok thank you now it works. :) I think you solution like the cleanest. Now I just need to understand the code.

Comment: Can you please tell me what the `/a-d` does?

Comment: @oRookie: see `dir /?`. It excludes foldernames.

Comment: @Stephan I saw that one. But I tried it out without the `/a-d` and the .txt didn't disappear, that's why I supposed that it does something more.

Comment: why should a file disappear, when you exclude folder names?

Comment: Using /a with the -d (minus directories) option removes folders from the list. If you had subfolders in the directory it would not be displayed. http://www.computerhope.com/dirhlp.htm

Comment: @Stephan - Sorry I meant the output. So the output was `out.txt` instead of `out` that's what I meant by disappear.

Comment: @I-LOVE-2-REVIVE but doesn't the `*txt` part already do that aswell?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims=." %%g in ('dir /b C:\Users\oRookie\Desktop\batch') do echo %%g >> out.txt
```

outputs a txt named out.txt containg only the text "out"